# Creating environment variables with Rails 6 and Heroku

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-6

How do I create a group of environment variables that can be used both locally in development and on Heroku using Rails 6?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are many different ways to configure environment variables, and people have many different preferences.

Personally, for my local development, I typically use [the dotenv gem](https://github.com/bkeepers/dotenv). I'll git-ignore .env, but I'll add a `.env.example` with all the vars I need stubbed out.

Then in my local checkout(s), I'll `cp .env.example .env`, and I will edit that .env file for all of my local configuration.

`dotenv-rails` includes a railtie to load environment variables from the `.env` file if they have not already been supplied as real env vars.

When I deploy to Heroku, I just use the Heroku console or GUI to set up my environment variables there.

Answer (score 0):

Rails credentials work great and they don't require any extra gems and keep all your app secrets in one location.

```
EDITOR=vim rails credentials:edit
```

You can access any variable you set in this encrypted file by `Rails.application.credentials.name_of_key`. Typically, your .gitignore file will exclude the `master.key` file, so to make it accessible on a cloud provider, you'd provide the single key as an environment variable for decryption.